# Error Running OpenTok on Android 17 Head Mounted Display - Golden-i

Tags: opentok

When I run the android sample here: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-demo

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find workable config for this device/camera
```

Does anyone know how to add a new camera config to the Opentok SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an older repository and I don't think its supported anymore. TokBox is currently distributing their android SDK beta through their website [here](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/). I have downloaded it and deployed the sample code to my android device and everything worked. Make sure you are deploying to your device and not the simulator.

Comment: I did as you stated and downloaded this version http://tokbox.com/downloads/opentok-2.0-android-sdk and it works on the golden-i device and also the Vuzix M100! Thank you very much as I had started looking into using https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye which works well but not as good as opentok.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out! Good luck with your development!